# Debug windows phone 7 via Visual Studio without internet

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, internet-connection

I'm debugging a windows phone 7 application using Visual Studio, and I'm trying to catch an exception that's thrown when the connection suddenly disappears. I'm looking for a solution that's much easier than just pulling out my ethernet cable every time I navigate with a webbrowser...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You don't need to.
I've done this by setting Fiddler as a proxy for the emulator, and closing it when I want to simulate no internet connection.

If you want to try this solution, you will find this link helpful.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2010/10/15/fiddler-and-the-windows-phone-emulator.aspx